# Parallelshell module not running on npm. What can be done?

Tags: node.js, npm, onchange, npm-scripts

**This is package.joson file's scripts my onchange and parallelshell modules are totally updated.**

````
    ```
"scripts": {
"start": "npm run watch:all",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"lite": "lite-server",
"scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
"watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
},
```
````

> If you want to run the code on MAC or linux replace /" with single
> quote(').

**An error comees up like this when I run this code.**
Please provide me a solution.
[image: Error messege showed in CMD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the version of parallelshell to 3.0.1

To do that run this commands on cmd:

```
npm uninstall parallelshell
npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.01
```